# ARCore: How to create an anchor from a session object without plane tracking?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I have been trying to do that, but I'm getting a NotTrackingException when I try the following

```
    Pose pose = Pose.makeTranslation(-0.41058916f, -0.6668466f, 0.04225248f);

    Anchor anchor = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession().createAnchor(pose);
```

or

```
    Pose pose = Pose.makeTranslation(-0.41058916f, -0.6668466f, 0.04225248f);

    Anchor anchor =new Session(this).createAnchor(pose);
```

Comment: In my opinion, I think you cannot create an anchor without plane tracking

Comment: @Subhamagarwal, can you tell me how I can achieve this effect using Sceneform? https://vimeo.com/294983387

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways you can set an anchor in your Arcore scene. One way, which sounds like it might meet your needs, is to set the anchor position relative to the camera focus - see this answer, which is tested and works:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53175458/334402

The key code, creating the anchor from the session object is:

```js
          //Add an Anchor and a renderable in front of the camera       
          Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
          float[] pos = { 0,0,-1 };
          float[] rotation = {0,0,0,1};
          Anchor anchor =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos, rotation));
          anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
          anchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
          anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

If you look at some of the other answers to that question also you can see some alternative, non-plan tracking, approaches also.