# Rendering 3d object on specified point without using plane detection in Arcore(sceneform)

Tags: android, arcore

I am working on a Augmented reality application where I have to place an 3d object on a specified point in the ar screen (ex - Placing an object on hand).Is is possible to do it without using a plane detector of Ar sceneform as I do not want it place it on the place but at specified point on screen.Please provide me a source if anyone has answer for it

Answer (score 0):

You can place an object at a point on the screen rather than on a plane - there are several approaches. One is to set an anchor relative to the camera position.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53175458/334402 and full code is available here if you want to play with it: https://github.com/mickod/LineView

Note, that this will put it at that point in the 'world' absolutely - i.e. not relative to a person's hand. So if the person moves their hand the renderable will remain in the place you put it, not move with their hand.